# Epsilon-delta reference-request

Tags: reference-request, epsilon-delta

I'm not an undergrad student, and as I'm living in Sweden this means that I am studying at a Gymnasium. In pre-university levels of teaching math in Sweden, the epsilon-delta method is not covered. So, I'm just wondering: could you please give me an example of an undergraduate book, that covers the topic of epsilon-delta method - at least has it included in it?

Would be appreciated if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Spivak's *Calculus* or Apostol's *Calculus Vol. I*.